# Some questions on proper acceleration in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, acceleration, covariance

I’m trying to solve an exercise in which I have to use the definition of proper acceleration, which is:

$$
a^{\mu}= u^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}u^{\mu}
$$

In the exercise, I deal with the acceleration along a certain curve $x^{\mu}(t)$. My question is the following one:

If I choose a frame in which $u^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}=(1,0,0,0)$ (I think one can always make this choice), then the acceleration would be $a^{\mu}=u^{0}\nabla_{0}u^{\mu}=\nabla_{0}u^{\mu}$, and since in this frame, $u^{\mu}=constant$ for every $\mu$, then acceleration would be $a^{\mu}=0$. But I'm quite sure this must be incorrect, since one can always choose $u^{\mu}$ to be $(1,0,0,0)$ but one cannot make acceleration disappear just by a choice of frame. So where am I wrong?

Another question that I don't fully understand is whether $a^{\mu}u_{\mu}=0$ is always true or not (i.e. if the proper four-acceleration is always normal to the four-velocity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame you are choosing must be the one that is *instantaneously* co-moving with the object.  If instead you are looking at some frame for which the object has $u^\mu$ at all times, then either the coordinate frame is non-inertial (in which case $\nabla_0 u^\mu \neq \partial_0 u^\mu$) or the coordinate frame *is* inertial (in which case the object is moving at constant velocity in an inertial frame, and the result $a^\mu = 0$ is correct.)

As far as the result $a^\mu u_\mu = 0$ goes, it is always true.  It follows from the fact that $u_\mu u^\mu = -1$ by definition.  Take the derivative of $u_\mu u^\mu$ along the worldling and expand out the resulting equation using the product rule to get the acceleration equation you want.

Comment: Right! So, just to be sure, if I want the object to have four-velocity $u^{\mu}=(1,0,0,0)$ at all times, then it would have $a^{\mu}=u^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}u^{\mu}=\nabla_{0}u^{\mu}=\Gamma^{\mu}_{0\rho}u^{\rho}=\Gamma^{\mu}_{00}$, right? Thank you very much!

Comment: @TopoLynch:  That looks right to me.